# What is Ron trying to say in Chapter Eleven of "Order of the Phoenix"

Tags: harry-potter, ron-weasley

I came across this scene in *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*. Ron is trying to say something, but I have no clue.

> Unfortunately, Ron's mouth was packed to exploding point again and all he could manage was "***node iddum eentup sechew***"
>
> > *Ronald Weasley*, Chapter 11, *Order of the Phoenix*

Comment: Question needs more context around the gibberish.

Comment: It might be helpful if you either showed more of the context or gave an edition and page number.

Comment: “I didn’t mean to upset you.” according to Quota when I Googled the original phrase https://www.quora.com/When-Ron-is-talking-to-Nearly-Headless-Nick-with-his-mouth-full-at-the-start-of-term-feast-what-is-he-trying-to-say-when-we-hear-Node-iddum-eentup-sechew

Comment: no (I ?) - deddu (didn't) - meen (mean) - tu (to)- upsech (upset)- ew (you)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Nearly Headless Nick was upset at something Ron said, considering it mockery of his death:

> ‘Terrified? I hope I, Sir Nicholas de Mimsy-Porpington, have never been guilty of cowardice in my life! The noble blood that
> runs in my veins –’
>
> ‘What blood?’ asked Ron. ‘Surely you haven’t still got –?’
>
> ‘It’s a figure of speech!’ said Nearly Headless Nick, now so annoyed
> his head was trembling ominously on his partially severed neck. ‘I
> assume I am still allowed to enjoy the use of whichever words I like,
> even if the pleasures of eating and drinking are denied me! But I am
> quite used to students poking fun at my death, I assure you!’

Therefore Ron was probably saying something like: "No, I didn't mean to upset you." (Or possibly "mock you").

As @seumasmac noted in the comments, it's easier to parse Ron's statement if you divide the words this way:
no/de iddu/m een/t/up sech/ew = "no, I didn't mean to upset you"

And as a [commenter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/77809/wiggo-the-wookie) said, this [Quora](https://www.quora.com/When-Ron-is-talking-to-Nearly-Headless-Nick-with-his-mouth-full-at-the-start-of-term-feast-what-is-he-trying-to-say-when-we-hear-Node-iddum-eentup-sechew) answer agrees.

This [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=DXznAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA484&dq=node%20iddum%20eentup%20sechew&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiM9520mZ38AhVOFlkFHeLdAfIQ6AF6BAgEEAI#v=onepage&q=node%20iddum%20eentup%20sechew&f=false) discusses how the garbled sentences in this chapter were translated into other languages:

> It goes “Node iddum eentup sechew” (189). Ron is telling
> Nearly-Headless Nick that he didn't mean to upset him. The Spanish,
> French and German translations of this passage show that the
> translators “got it” and were able to present the puzzle to
> their readers.

Comment: As further confirmation: In the version translated into German, Ron says "Nö isch wollschi nisch feraaschn", clearly meant to be "nö, ich wollte Sie nicht verarschen" = "no, I didn't mean to make fun of you".

Comment: Thanks for that - I found another cite about translations into other languages as well

Comment: It's easier to unmangle if you shift the spacing: "no deiddu meen t upsech ew" == "no didn't mean to upset you"

Comment: Congratulations on your win; https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13833/and-the-best-new-user-of-2022-is. Speech! Speech!